# jQuery ID attr

Tags: jquery

```
$("a.close").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    alert(id);
    $(this).parents("div.venue:first").fadeOut("Fast");
    return false;
});
```

Any ideas why the alert isn't correctly popping up the current divs ID?

**Final code, thanks below for pointing my stupid error**

```
var id = $(this).parents("div.venue:first").attr("id");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your selector is working on an anchor:

```
$("a.close")
```

I'm guessing you mean the div after your alert, try this:

```
$("a.close").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    alert($(this).parents("div.venue:first").attr('id'));
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The element you are trying to get the id for is an a not a div.

Answer (score 0):

You're showing the id of the `<a>` element, not a div

Answer (score 0):

If you want the parent DIV's id, you'll need to traverse up to the parent before you get the attribute.

```
var id = $(this).closest('div').attr('id');
```